# plex folder access

Tags: 15.10, plex

I am running Plex on Ubuntu 15.10 in VirtualBox on Windows.
I created a second virtual disk and attached it to the VM.
There is no problem with it in Ubuntu as I can create folders and files.
However Plex cannot see any folders or files when adding to library. It can see the drive but nothing else.

I tried changing permissions and ownership to no avail the method here: [How to make folders ' seen' by PLEX](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293704/how-to-make-folders-seen-by-plex) did not work.

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
[Plex Media Manager sees external NTFS drive but doesn't see directories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620363/plex-media-manager-sees-external-ntfs-drive-but-doesnt-see-directories)

Add Plex user to the plugdev group by entering

```
 sudo gpasswd -a plex plugdev
```

right-click your external drive in the directory browser and go to properties to get its location

in the terminal enter

```
sudo chmod 775 external drive location; ie media/computername
```

right-click your Plex media folder on your external drive and copy the location

In the terminal enter

```
sudo chmod -R 775 Plex media folder location; ie media/computername/ntfsdrivevolumename
```

Comment: Yes that did work

Comment: Following from Dru smiths' answer. Its better to not use chmod 777, as it gives full access to everyone, which can be dangerous. Using chmod 775, is better as it doesn't give WRITE permissions to others. here is a link to read to educate you on permissions.
https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/